# Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: name

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I randomly started getting this error `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: name` on my app using ember-cli.
I have only two routes

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('buy');
  this.route('rent');
});
```

no controllers, my index route redirects me to `buy`

```
redirect: function() {
  this.transitionTo('buy');
}
```

and my `rent` route also renders the `buy` template

```
renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('buy');
}
```

I don't have a `rent` or `index` template.
I have no idea where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out why, turns out I had two inputs with the same id on my template,
`{{ input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="full-width" }}` twice in different places. It would be useful if the error message could be more informative and give you a line on your actual code instead of showing just the line `throw new EmberError("Assertion Failed: " + desc);` on you `vendor.js` file.

Comment: In my case when I this.transitionTo('anyTemplate') for store multiple templates in a "anyTemplate" It's not rendering properly the things. Its only renders the parent template in "anyTemplat". You have any Idea why it is happening ?

Comment: Your duplicate ID may be in a form field inside of another component you're including on the page, don't simply look for it within the same file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I ended up just searching all the elements in the Chrome Elements tab for the ID that was identified as duplicated. This turned out to be a great way to find where the duplicate IDs were coming from.