# Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: 2 - EmberJs

Tags: ember.js

I am getting this following error when I am running an Ember application

```
Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: 2
```

- can somebody please help me in finding what would be the reasons for this error and how to fix them - any help would be very very helpful as I am new to Ember - thanks a lot

Comment: Without a snippet, it will be hard to understand and debug the issue. That being said, recently I faced this when I use an element modifier with invalid syntax.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029299/uncaught-error-assertion-failed-attempted-to-register-a-view-with-an-id-alread

Answer (score 0):

You have one or more elements/components attempting to render with the id of "2". If you didn't hard-code multiple components with the id of "2", then check your dynamically created ids. You may have some sort of `id=someValue` rule, where `someValue` can potentially be repeated in the same view.

It's possible in Ember, for example, to set `id=index` in an `{{#each records as |record index|}}` loop. If you had more than one loop in a view using `index` as the `id`, then you could get this error. Can't know for sure without seeing more code.